# Is upgrading from 11.04 with GNOME3 to 11.10 safe?

Tags: 11.04, 11.10, gnome

I have an 11.04 machine with gnome 3.0 shell and i would like to upgrade it to 11.10. My concern is some sort of conflict between the gnome 3 package i have installed and 11.10 during the upgrade. Anyone got ideas on what might happen if I upgrade? Has anyone tried this?

Answer (score 1):

I know it's always better for me to back up what I want to keep and install instead of upgrade. I've never had an upgrade go very smoothly. I think most people would tell you to do a fresh install.